# How do I eager load a model off the back of another model?

Tags: php, laravel

Hopefully this should add some context to my question. I have 3 models.

My Build Model:

```
public function buildComment(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\buildComment');
}
public function buildQuestion(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\buildQuestion');
}
```

My buildQuestion Model:

```
public function build(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Build');
    }
```

buildComments Model:

```
public function build(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Build');
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function viewQuestion(buildQuestion $buildQuestion){
    $builds = Build::with('buildComment')->get();

    return view('pages.questionView',compact('buildQuestion', 'builds'));
}
```

here is my view:

```
@foreach($buildQuestion->build as $build)
       <ul class="list-group">
           <li class="list-group-item clearfix active">Build suggestion by: {{$build->user->name}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Processor: <a href="/parts/cpu/{{$build->processor->id}}">{{$build->processor->name}}</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Graphics Card: <a href="/parts/gpu/{{$build->videoCard->id}}">{{$build->videoCard->name}}</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">RAM: <a href="/parts/memory/{{$build->memory->id}}">{{$build->memory->name}}</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Motherboard: <a href="/parts/motherboard/{{$build->motherboard->id}}">{{$build->motherboard->name}}</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Power Supply: <a href="/parts/power-supply/{{$build->powerSupply->id}}">{{$build->powerSupply->name}}</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Storage: <a href="/parts/storage/{{$build->storage->id}}">{{$build->storage->name}}</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Optical Drive: <a href="/parts/optical-drive/{{$build->opticalDrive->id}}">{{$build->opticalDrive->name}}</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix"><strong>Build Total Price: £{{$build->processor->price + $build->videoCard->price + $build->memory->price + $build->motherboard->price + $build->powerSupply->price + $build->storage->price + $build->opticalDrive->price}}</strong></li>
        </ul>
        @foreach($build->buildComment as $comment)
        {{$comment->body}}
        @endforeach
        <form action="/build-comment/post/{{$build->id}}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="body">Comment </label>
                <textarea class="form-control"  name="body"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        @endforeach
```

I am trying to fetch the comments belonging to the build.

The buildQuestion has many builds, the build has many comments.

How can I represent this and retrieve the comments for the build?

Comment: I think what you want is `$buildQuestion->load(['builds', 'builds.comments']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them all in one query with nested eager loading.

```
//one buildquestion with all the builds & comments
$buildQuestion = BuildQuestion::with('build.buildComment')->find(1); 

return view('pages.questionView',compact('buildQuestion'));
```

In your view, nest your foreach

```
@foreach($buildQuestion->build as $build)
    //display stuff

    @foreach($build->buildComment as $comment)
         {{ $comment->body}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, This seems promising! But I have separate pages with each buildQuestions though. Each build question displays the builds related to them, then with the comments below the builds. Your answer causes all the comments to be displayed underneath the build, related to the build or not. I need the comments to be displayed for the related build. I think this is to do with the find().

Comment: Then try with your previous query but keep the double foreach. You have to loop through all the build, and loop through all comments.

Comment: Works, good man! I'll update in case you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($buildQuestion->build as $build)
   <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item clearfix active">Build suggestion by: {{$build->user->name}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Processor: <a href="/parts/cpu/{{$build->processor->id}}">{{$build->processor->name}}</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Graphics Card: <a href="/parts/gpu/{{$build->videoCard->id}}">{{$build->videoCard->name}}</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">RAM: <a href="/parts/memory/{{$build->memory->id}}">{{$build->memory->name}}</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Motherboard: <a href="/parts/motherboard/{{$build->motherboard->id}}">{{$build->motherboard->name}}</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Power Supply: <a href="/parts/power-supply/{{$build->powerSupply->id}}">{{$build->powerSupply->name}}</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Storage: <a href="/parts/storage/{{$build->storage->id}}">{{$build->storage->name}}</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Optical Drive: <a href="/parts/optical-drive/{{$build->opticalDrive->id}}">{{$build->opticalDrive->name}}</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix"><strong>Build Total Price: £{{$build->processor->price + $build->videoCard->price + $build->memory->price + $build->motherboard->price + $build->powerSupply->price + $build->storage->price + $build->opticalDrive->price}}</strong></li>
    </ul>
    @foreach($build->buildComment as $comment)
    {{$comment->body}}
    @endforeach
    <form action="/build-comment/post/{{$build->id}}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Comment </label>
            <textarea class="form-control"  name="body"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    @endforeach
```

I nested another foreach after @EddyTheDove suggested making this change and it worked.